# How to check recently stopped/started EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way by which in can check the recently stopped/started/terminated EC2 instance for my account? I wish to have a `recent history` option so that I will be able to see the recently stopped/started/terminated EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is partly possible, but not easy.

Checking for recently launched instances is easy. The *DescribeInstances* API function can give a list of all instances, including their current state and launch time, and you can sort the result.

Recently stopped is harder. You will have to use the *DescribeInstanceStatus* API function to get a list of all instances, filter by those who are stopped, and see if there is a reachability failed event with a timestamp of when that occurred.

You may not be able to do what you want for terminated instances at all. At some point, terminated instances disappear from the API entirely, since they no longer exist. You may be able to do the same kind of thing as for recently stopped instances; it would take some experimental programming to discover that.

Except for listing recently launched instances, this is all pretty difficult. The [API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-apis.html) could get you started.